# C# override base generic method cannot cast T to T?

Tags: c#

Trying to override a method that returns the generic type.

The compiler error is:

`CS0266 cannot implicit convert type 'T' to 'T?'.`

Simple example:

```cs
public class Base
{
    public virtual T? Method<T>()
    {
        return default;
    }
}

public class Class : Base
{
    public override T? Method<T>()
    {
        return base.Method<T>();
    }
}
```

I understand that this is because the base method lacks a class constraint, but I am calling to the base method so there shouldn't be any conversion happening, right?

Comment: The inconsistency here is that the compiler allows the first declaration as a courtesy (pretending that `T?` is actually `T`, with nullability warnings) but then when you override, you must use the actual, undecorated type of the method (which is `T`) -- and to add insult to injury you then get a "possible null reference" warning on your `base` call that needs to be suppressed. Despite all that, when using `Class.Method<T>` it recognizes the return type is nullable. Looks buggy, and if it's not a bug it's a very poor usability story.

Comment: Needs C# 9.0 if not constrainted.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#generics

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @lidqy, that article helped a lot. Found I could do this to get it to compile.

```cs
public class Base {
    public virtual T? Method<T>() {
        return default;
    }
}

public class Class : Base {
    [return: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.MaybeNull()]
    public override T Method<T>() {
        return base.Method<T>();
    }
}
```